# Does msvsmon work fine on Win CE?

Tags: windows-ce, remote-debugging

I would like to ask can I just put "msvsmon.exe" to target device and remote debugging like Win XP on Win CE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`msvsmon.exe` is a desktop Windows executable.  It will not run under Windows CE.

To remote debug to a Windows CE device - which is a very common task - use CoreCon to connect from Visual Studio.  The process [is outlined in this article](http://nicolasbesson.blogspot.com/2008/02/smart-device-deployment-and-debugging.html).